# PHP/MySQL - building a nav menu hierarchy

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, menu, hierarchy

So the final menu will look something like this:

```
Item B
    Item B-1
        Item B-1-2
        Item B-1-1
Item A
    SubItem A-1
    SubItem A-2
Item C
```

Based on the following DB records:

```
id        menu_title          parent_menu_id    menu_level    weight
1         Item A                0                           1                     1
2         Item B                0                           1                     0
3         Item C                0                           1                     2
4         SubItem A-2       1                           2                     1
5         Item B-1             2                           2                     0
6         Item B-1-1          5                           3                     1
7         SubItem A-1       1                           2                     0
8         Item B-1-2          5                           3                     0
```

**How would I go about displaying?** My guess is it'll involve storing all the items into a multidimensional array, then looping through it somehow...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dealing with the data structure as you have it will often involve recursion or multiple queries to build the tree.

Have you considered other ways of storing a hierarchy? Check out modified pre-order traversal - here's a nice [PHP based article about this](http://www.sitepoint.com/article/hierarchical-data-database/).

Comment: This model is error-prone when it comes to insertion of new elements or moving items around and IMHO not worth the supposed advantages.

Comment: @cletus - Its not meant to be rapidly updated constantly, still if you use transactions and stored procedures, then update/insert related errors go away.

Comment: What about updating the index when you add nodes etc. On a large dataset and rapid additions it would mean a whole lot of updates to the index

Answer (score 8):

Hierarchical data is somewhat annoying in a relationsal database (excluding Oracle, which has operators in `START WITH/CONNECT BY` to deal with this).  There are basically [two models](http://extjs.com/forum/showthread.php?t=33096): adjacency list and nested sets.

You've chosen adjacency sets, which is what I typically do too.  It's far easier to change than the nested set model, although the nested set model can be retrieved in the correct order in a single query.  Adjacency lists can't be.  You'll need to build an intermediate data structure (tree) and then convert that into a list.

What I would do (and have done recently in fact) is:

- select the entire menu contents in one query ordered by parent ID;
- Build a tree of the menu structure using associative arrays or classes/objects;
- Walk that tree to create nested unordered lists; and
- Use a jQuery plug-in like [Superfish](http://users.tpg.com.au/j_birch/plugins/superfish/) to turn that list into a menu.

You build something like this:

```
$menu = array(
  array(
    'name' => 'Home',
    'url' => '/home',
  ),
  array(
    'name' => 'Account',
    'url' => '/account',
    'children' => array(
      'name' => 'Profile',
      'url' => '/account/profile',
    ),
  ),
  // etc
);
```

and convert it into this:

```
<ul class="menu">;
  <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/account">Account Services</a>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="/account/profile">Profile</a></li>
...
```

The PHP for generating the menu array from is reasonably straightforward but a bit finnicky to solve.  You use a recursive tree-walking function that builds the HTML nested list markup but will leave it's implementation as an exercise for the reader. :)

Comment: The hardest part for me is figuring out how to structure the array/object. Could you point me to an example?

Comment: @Matt check out cakePHP's implementation ACL, specifically the Tree behavior...its a little abstract but still should be helpful.  http://api.cakephp.org/class_tree_behavior.html

Answer (score 1):

The way your storing hierarchical data isn't as efficient as you might want.  I read the article [Managing Hierarchical Data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/) a few years ago and have since found it as *the* best solution to managing hierarchy based data in SQL.  Next best benefit is that I believe you can grab the entire tree with one query.

Answer (score 1):

I just posted in a similar question my own approach to transform MySQL hierarchical data (adjacency list) into a menu (HTML)

It does **not** use recursion. And it requires a **single query** to the database.

Read more at

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871861#3368622

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Another simple way you can generate hierarchy if you don't want to use nested sets is to use a simple text string in front.

```
Item B
    Item B-1
        Item B-1-2
        Item B-1-1
Item A
    SubItem A-1
    SubItem A-2
Item C
```

Would become

```
1 Item B
  1.1 Item B1
    1.1.1 Item B11
    1.1.2 Item B12
2 Item A
  2.1 Item A1
  2.2 Item B2
3 Item C
```

The digit in front of each item could be stored in a field and parsed based on length (representing the depth of where it is) to tell you everything you need to know about where it goes.

I use nested set hierarchies for more complicated stuff that requires calculation,e tc, but I find this approach has served well