# Hierarchical recursion menu with PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, recursion

This should (hopefully) be a pretty easy question for some of you to answer.

I have a working Recursive menu from a mySQL database, now my main problem is:

What is the best way to create the URL?  I would prefer to bring in the title of each row like /eggs/milk/bacon/.  Eggs being level 0 like: eggs-0, milk-1, bacon-2.  Any ideas on how to dynamicly output this?

I am pretty much going for what "cletus" said a few comments down on this question:
[PHP/MySQL - building a nav menu hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477793/php-mysql-building-a-nav-menu-hierarchy)

But I need a bit more explanation on how to do it.

Comment: Are you having trouble creating the URL part of the unordered list as described in Cletus' post?

Comment: Correct, the URL part.  I'm not sure how to have them stack, /one/two/three/ etc..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unless you plan to modify your menu tree often, pre-storing the required hierarchical URL for each menu item is probably the easiest (for run-time resolution that is).

If you expect the tree to be modified often enough, lets say - through a web interface, then it would be easier to generate the paths every time you read the menu, something like this:

```
 id | name   | parent
----+--------+-------
 0  | eggs   | NULL
 1  | milk   | 0
 2  | bacon  | 1
 3  | tomato | 0
 4  | lettuce| 1

foreach (query("SELECT * FROM menu ORDER BY parent ASC") as $row) {
  $menuitem = array_merge(array(), $row);
  $menuLookup[$menuitem['id']] &= $menuitem;
  if ($menuitem['parent'] == null) {
    $menuitem['path'] = "/" . $menuitem['name'];
    $menu[] &= $menuitem[];
  } else {
    $parent &= $menuLookup[$menuitem['parent']];
    $menuitem['path'] = $parent['path'] . "/" . $menuitem['name'];
    $parent['menu'][] &= $menuitem;
  }
}
```

I haven't debugged this code, only tested it for correctness ;-)

Comment: I should of stated that I'm not a php pro but from what I can tell you are basically saying "If 'parent' exists then put 'name' into the parent['path'] array and move on?  So this would eventually lead to /milk/bacon/ etc?

Comment: not exactly - $menu would eventually hold a hierarchy of menu items by placing children into the 'menu' array of their parent. This is standard "un-flatten my list" stuff.

Comment: The only gimmick here is composing 'path' by prefixing the current name with the parent's 'path', there by recursively building each child's path from the sum of its parents.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the help!  I will see what I can do.  I am still learning how to properly use arrays, I was trying to just use a variable to "stack" the path values recursively.  But obviously it would just be overwriting itself (I think, haha!).

Comment: please note the use of &= to get a reference to the the arrays instead of simple = . The reason is that I don't want to copy the array content - I want to use the same instance so that when I assign data to it, all the references see it.

Answer (score 4):

Well, if you want a hierarchy, be best method I know of is called "Modified Preorder Tree Traversal" that is described in great detail [in this Sitepoint article](http://www.sitepoint.com/print/hierarchical-data-database/), starts about halfway down.

The main difference from what Guss suggested is that it's a bit more performant and a lot easier to only fetch the part of the tree you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for the info!  I did check out both methods before starting this project however the most rows I would be dealing with is 75 max so Tree Traversal seemed like overkill.  However, I am now seeing that Tree traversal would of given me a bit more control. *le sigh.*

Answer (score 0):

i wrote something in groovy: http://blog.srvme.de/2009/11/29/reading-a-reflexive-association-in-a-recursive-way-for-grails-and-groovy/