# Category with Subcategory PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, html, codeigniter, html-lists

i have MySql Table name 'category', in that table i have

```
id   catname   parent_id
1    animals
2    vegs        
3    dog        1
4    cat        1
5    carrot     2
```

i just wanna display this data in html nested 'ul' like

```
<ul>
  <li>Animals
      <ul>
         <li>dog</li>
         <li>cat</li>
      </ul>
  </li>
  <li>Vegs
     <ul>
         <li>Carrot</li>
      </ul>
 </li>
</ul>
```

with php, please help me to get this data with php(CodeIgniter) and display.

Comment: This question has been made several times here. Please use the "search" feature of the site.

Comment: For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2871861/how-to-build-unlimited-level-of-menu-through-php-and-mysql/  -  and see the "Related" questions in the right-side of this one to get lots of similar questions / answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are the three components for your question: controller, model and view...

```
<!-- THE VIEW -->

<ul>
<?php foreach($main_cat->result() as $rowm) : ?>

    <li><?php echo $rowm->catname ?>
        <ul>
        <?php
            $id = $rowm->id;
            $sec_cat = $this->yourmodel->get_secondary($id);
            foreach($sec_cat->result() as $rows) :
        ?>

            <li><?php echo $rows->catname ?></li>

        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    </li>

<?php endforeach; ?>
</ul>



<!-- THE CONTROLLER -->

<?php

class Welcome extends CI_Controller {   
   function index()
   {
      $data['main_cat'] = $this->yourmodel->get_main();
      $this->load->view('welcome_view',$data);
   }
} 
?>



  <!-- THE MODEL -->

<?php
class Yourmodel extends CI_Model {

function get_main()
{
    $this->db->where('parent_id','');
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query;
}

function get_secondary($parent)
{
    $this->db->where('parent_id',$parent);
    $query = $this->db->get('category');
    return $query;
}
}
?>
```